# I want to add layout="responsive" in image url builder sanity and nextjs

Tags: next.js, bots, sanity

I want to add layout="responsive" in image url builder sanity and nextjs

code :

```
{blogs.slice(0).map((item) => {
            return item.category == "technology" &&
              <Link key={item.slug.current} href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>
                <article className="ip oo ik" data-aos="fade-up">
                  <header>
                    <a className="ic re" href="blog-post.html">
                      <figure className="tq ig fe o_ oq">
                        <Image className="tj tz su ik an p o lz ci cl CCC" style={{ "backgroundImage": `url(${builder.image(item.mainImage).width(200).dpr(2).url() || '/../public/assests/images/ImageNotAvalible.png'})` }} src='/' layout='responsive' width={400} height={250} />
                      </figure>
                    </a>
                    <div className="rd">
                      <ul className="ip ou fb fk nl">
                        <li className="nc"> <Link key={item.categoryI.current} href={"/" + item.categoryI}><a className="id fp ll ah aa oj uh ch lz cr cf" href="#0">{item.categoryI}</a></Link> </li>
                        <li className="nc"> <Link key={item.categoryII.current} href={"/" + item.categoryII}><a className="id fp ll ah aa oj uv cd lz cr cf" href="#0">{item.categoryII}</a></Link> </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <h3 className="h3 ra"> <a className="c_ lz cr cf text-hover text-2xl " href="blog-post.html">{item.title}</a> </h3>
                  </header>
                  <p className="fm li sz">{item.metadesc}</p>
                  <footer className="ip ol rv"> <a href="#0">
                    {/* <Image className="oj sq rl" src="/" width="40" height="40" alt="Author 01" /> */}
                  </a>
                    <div className="fk"> <a className="lr c_ lz cr cf text-hover" href="#0">{item.Name}</a> <span className="lc"> - </span> <span className="lf">{item.publishedAt}</span> </div>
                  </footer>
                </article>
              </Link>
          })}
```

The method for responsive layout given in sanity docs is not working.

Comment: const associated with this code const client = createClient({
    projectId: "yr4cfo81",
    dataset: "production",
    useCdn: false
  });
  const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client)

Comment: Can you please clarify what the issue is exactly? What is not working?

Comment: because im using this command to displauy images style={{ "backgroundImage": `url(${builder.image(item.mainImage).width(200).dpr(2).url() || '/../public/assests/images/ImageNotAvalible.png'})` }} src='/' layout='responsive' width={400} height={250} />
                      </figure>

Comment: Is `builder.image(item.mainImage).width(200).dpr(2).url()` not returning the expected value?

Comment: the image is returning but the only properties working is .width(200).dpr(2).url() but the rest layout="responsive" or width& height set on image is not working